# Great_Expectations Conditional Expectation in Spark 3.2.1 with Pandas API in DataBricks

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, databricks, great-expectations

We want to implement Great_Expectations' in DataBricks with Conditional Expectation. According to GE's documentation https://docs.greatexpectations.io/docs/reference/expectations/conditional_expectations is only available for Pandas this argument must be set to "pandas" by default, thus, demanding the appropriate syntax. Other engines might be implemented in the future.

Does anyone knows if it can be implemented in Spark 3.2.1 which integrated with Pandas APIs? if not, any suggestion for handle conditional expectation in DataBricks with Spark 3.2.1?

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is now *experimentally* supported w/ Spark. The documentation is still being updated, but you should now be able to set a `row_condition` on an Expectation against a Spark datasource by passing  `great_expectations__experimental__` as the `condition_parser`.

Comment: How about SqlAlchemy engine?

Comment: Exactly the same, though you may experience unexpected behavior depending on dialect, and will need to explicitly declare columns. For example, a valid Postgresql row_condition would look like `'col("Age")>35'`

Comment: Does GE version matters here please ?